# PrimeFaces dialog box not appearing

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Iam using primefaces 4.0 .I want to use dialog box . When i used it its printing the dialog content in the same page on load itself  .Dialog box not opening

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
    <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic" onclick="dlg.show()" type="button" />
</h:panelGrid>

<p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">
   <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
</p:dialog>
```

also tried

in facesconfig.xml 
       org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener
       org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler
       
       org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler

Thanks in advance

Comment: `dlg.show()` doesn't match the value in `widgetVar` (`dlg1`). Try to fix this first.

Comment: it should be dlg1.show();

Comment: even after fixing its not working

Comment: I tried using <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" type="button" />.This is also not working

Comment: removed type = "button" still not working

Comment: If you have access to firebug, see if you can find a javascript object called dlg1 in the console. Try to invoke the dlg1.show() method from the console as well.

Comment: I tried your code (with the `dlg1` correction) and it works fine by me. The problem is elsewhere (in the page, config,...)

Answer (score 0):

I missed adding
       h:head

Thanks all for your response